# How to search for an entity before the SaveChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This question is related [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393380/how-can-i-create-multiple-entities-before-the-savechanges).

I need to be able to search for a **Signature** entity before it is made available through the **SaveChanges**.

This is the function that searches, and adds if not found, a **Signature**:

```
public static async Task<int?> TryUpdateSignature(MyDbContext db, Signature oldSignUser, Date? newDate, string userName)
{
    int? SignatureID = null; //Returns null if no date

    //Validate if there is a new date
    if ((IsNothing(oldSignUser) && newDate != null) || (oldSignUser != null && oldSignUser.DateSign != newDate))
    {
        Signature recSignature = Await db.Signature.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.UserID == userName && s.DateSign == newDate);
        if (IsNothing(recSignature))
        {
            recSignature = new Signature;
            recSignature.UserID = userName;
            recSignature.DateSign = newDate;
            db.Signature.Add(recSignature);
        }

        SignatureID = recSignature.SignatureID;
    }
    else if (oldSignUser != null && newDate != null)
    {       //If no change, keep old signature
        SignatureID = oldSignUser.SignatureID;
    }

    return SignatureID;
}
```

The problem arises when it's called multiple time during the same Edit post. The first time, it creates the new **Signature** and returns the new ID. The second time however, it should find the first **Signature** and return its ID but, instead, creates a new **Signature** since the first one is only in memory.

I know that the **Find** function can look into memory for speed but it requires the ID so no luck there.

A dirty solution would be to call **SaveChanges** after each add but I would prefer not to.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in this scenario since it's the same DbContext you can go to the DbSet's Local first to try and locate a matching entity before doing the FirstOrDefault which will go to the DB.

```
Signature recSignature = db.Signature.Local.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserID == userName && s.DateSign == newDate);
if (IsNothing(recSignature))
{
  recSignature = Await db.Signature.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.UserID == userName && s.DateSign == newDate);
}

if (IsNothing(recSignature))
{
  // ...
}
```